# How can i properly block method until object counter gets > 0?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

You can think that class is strange, but it's educational, so i have to do it this way.

```
class petriPool {
    private int[] nodes = new int[3];
    private int counter;

    private readonly object _lock = new object(); 

    public petriPool (int n, int m) {
        this.nodes[0] = n;
        this.nodes[1] = 0;
        this.nodes[2] = 0;
        this.counter  = m;
    }

    public bool start() {
        lock (_lock) {
            if (this.nodes[0] != 0 && counter != 0) {
                this.nodes[0]--;
                this.nodes[1]++;
                counter--;
                return true;   
            } else
                return false;
    }}

    public bool stop() {
        lock (_lock) {
            if (this.nodes[1] != 0) {
                this.nodes[1]--;
                this.nodes[2]++;
                counter++;
                return true;   
            } else
                return false;
    }}
}
```

I need to make `start()` method wait until `counter` get value `> 0`. I can do so:

```
public bool start() {
    while (this.counter == 0) {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    lock (_lock) {
        if (this.nodes[0] != 0 && counter != 0) {
            this.nodes[0]--;
            this.nodes[1]++;
            counter--;
            return true;   
        } else
            return false;
}}
```

But isn't here any better solution? I mean it looks like i can lose less time to sleep.

To see, for what it needed. I call `start` before starting thread and `stop` in the end of thread. So counter must reflect maximum number of threads running in the same time.

Comment: Your code is hardly recognizable as C# code. Have a look at the [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx). This looks like straight out of a C++ book,

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna read this as i solve all urgent problems.

Comment: You can also look at `BlockingCollection<T>` instead of an array for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Signalling like this is done by using Event classes. In your case, [ManualResetEventSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be enough.

You can [Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289529(v=vs.110).aspx) for it instead of the while-loop and you can [Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim.set(v=vs.110).aspx) it when the counter hits zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of using `ManualResetEvent' for comminicating between two threads.

Following untested code might help.

```
class petriPool 
{
    private int[] nodes = new int[3];
    private int counter;
    private ManualResetEvent mevent;

    private readonly object _lock = new object(); 

    public petriPool (int n, int m) 
    {
        mevent= new ManualResetEvent(false);
        this.nodes[0] = n;
        this.nodes[1] = 0;
        this.nodes[2] = 0;
        this.counter  = m;
    }

    public bool start() 
    {
        lock (_lock) 
        {
            if (this.nodes[0] != 0 && counter != 0) 
            {
                this.nodes[0]--;
                this.nodes[1]++;
                counter--;

                if(counter>0) mevent.Set();

                return true;   
            } else
                return false;   
        }
    }

    public bool stop() 
    {
        mevent.WaitOne();

        lock (_lock) {


            if (this.nodes[1] != 0) {
                this.nodes[1]--;
                this.nodes[2]++;
                counter++;
                return true;   
            } else
                return false;
        }

        //reset 'mevent' if you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: I added some explanation to question. I create object with 5 n and 2 counter. All threads started in one time and as all ended, program just stop running. Looks like something wrong.